# Android Bottom Sticky Button moves up down on scroll

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a Tabbed Layout and I want to have a Sticky Button at the bottom.
When the layout is larger than the screen size I can scroll up and the Tool Bar also scrolls up to align the Tabs as the Top most Element. When I scroll, the Button also scrolls up because I have a padding at the bottom to keep it in state when it is launched.

[image: Before Scroll]                          [image: After Scroll (Button moves up)]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="io.sampleapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="io.sampleapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/mRecyclerview"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottomButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
        android:background="#555555"
        android:text="dummy"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So what is expected? The first screenshot or the second one?

Comment: @Rajkiran when i scroll the button should not move up. it should be at the bottom

Comment: Why do you have this padding of 54dp at the bottom? To compensate for the navigation bar?

Comment: @Rajkiran its there to compensate tablayout- for tabs, if i remove tablayout everthing works perfectly without paddingBottom, but when we add tablayout button is pushed down where by button is not visible and further we had to add padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Button should be outside `CoordinatorLayout` tag, try to remove the Button from `fragment_main.xml` and add it to `activity_main.xml` like:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

... />
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
 ...

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bottomButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
    android:background="#555555"
    android:text="dummy"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

in the other fragments if you don't need the button you can make it invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Put your button outside of RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1):

What i could say is probably you are trying to achieve a use case without following the proper material design guidelines.

Why dont you use FAB aka [FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, remove margin bottom for button and add margin bottom to recyclerview of height same as Button's height

Answer (score 1):

I don't wanted to have the floating Button outside the fragment holder or the Recycler o whatever the View is, as the responses above suggest. But I wanted to have the button inside the Fragment, and maintain it with the screen logic.

So here is what I could achieved.  If we suppose that we have an `AppBarLayout`, and inside of it we have a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and these views are wrapped inside a `CoordinatorLayout`.

I created a `BaseFragment` with a public function called `setOffsetChanged`:

```
public void setOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset){
 //Empty function
}
```

And in the `MainActivity`, add the object that create reference to the `AppBarLayout`:

```
private AppBarLayout appBar;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    appBar = findViewById(R.id.appBar);
    appBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
}
```

implement the listener `AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener{}
```

And add its function:

```
    @Override
public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
    BaseFragment fragment = (BaseFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()
   .get(getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size() - 1);
    fragment.setOffsetChanged(appBarLayout, verticalOffset);
}
```

Ok, now we only have to add this function from the `BaseFragment` in our fragment where we have the "floating" button:

```
    @Override
public void setOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
    super.setOffsetChanged(appBarLayout, verticalOffset);
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) buttonHolder.getLayoutParams();
    int marginBottomDP = (int) (SCALE * 100 + 0.5f); //100 because that is the space needed to appear besides the collapsed AppBarLayout
    buttonParams.bottomMargin = ((verticalOffset * -1) - marginBottomDP) * -1;
    buttonHolder.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
}
```

And that's it. We have now, our always floating button at the bottom of the screen.